# How to list the titles of html pages with links on the home page in Django

Tags: python, django, listview, django-templates

[Picture of my window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Vg1.png)

I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I am new to Django. I am building a website and I have articles saved as template files. I want to display all of their titles with links directed to those templates but I want to automatically list them so if I add a new template to the folder, the home page will have the new link to that template. Is there a way to do that?

So as I show in the picture... I have a folder for article sites, but I want to list their titles and the URLs on the home page. I know we can do it manually but I want to automatically list them, so every time we add one or remove an article, the home page list should get modified automatically.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is an efficient way of doing what you want to do. But i think if your article has same features and if it is showing in the same html structure i prefer using database for storing each article and use only one template for rendering those details.